# Laravel: keep the checkbox selection after a validation error?

Tags: laravel

In my form I want the checkboxes to keep their states (checked or unchecked) after a validation error.
This is what I have so far:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="delete-user" class="form-check-input" data-data-section="users" name="permissions[]" value="delete-user" {{ (is_array(old('permissions')) && in_array(1, old('permissions'))) ? ' checked' : '' }}>
```

But it looks that the old() function doesn't work.
I also tried:

```
old('permissions.'.$key)
```

where $key is the checkbox array index but it doesn't work neither.
Any idea ?

Comment: Value of your checkbox is `delete-user`. So don't you think in checked condition there should be `delete-user` instead of `1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are an invalid value pass in the in_array function

Try this:

```
value="delete-user" {{ (is_array(old('permissions')) && in_array('delete-user', old('permissions'))) ? ' checked' : '' }}>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but for whatever reason it still doesn't work. It really looks like old() doesn't work at all.

Comment: Ok it works now. I was testing with a simple redirection:  
`return redirect()->route('admin.users.roles.edit')->with('error', __('message'));` and it turns out that the inputs are not flashed. On the other hand the inputs are automaticaly flashed with the validation requests.